# Specify URL in Axios Mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, axios

I have my front-end unit test working, but I don't like that I *have* to put my `mockAxios` calls in the order in which they occur when the test runs. In the example below, I had my `mockAxios.post` calls reversed and the test failed. Is there a way I can specify the URL within my mock setup so I'm sure that mock applies only to that specific call when the code runs?

Edit: It looks like I can use axios-mock-adapter to do what I want. I'm wondering if I should change to use that.
https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter

```
  it('shows error when axios call fails', (done) => {

    // ToDo: I don't like having to depend on order for mocking axios. We should be able to
    // explicitly define what happens for a specific call. Look into this.

    // Mock the call to get employees
    mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject({ error: 'some error message' })
    );

    // Mock the logging call
    mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ data: '' })
    );    

    const expected = {
      type: 'SET_BANNER_VISIBILITY',
      payload: {
        visible: true,
        type: 'error',
        text: `We're having trouble loading employees. Please try again in a few minutes. ` +
          `If the problem still exists, please contact support.`,
        showSupportButton: true
      }
    };

    return mockStore.dispatch(actions.getEmployees()).then(() => {
      expect(mockStore.getActions().pop()).toEqual(expected);      
      done();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using an extra library be an option: https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter ?

It seems like there is a ticket open for that functionality on jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6180

Comment: Ha. I *just* added that edit to my post. Sure, we could change, and maybe we should. I'm still curious to know if it's possible with the current testing framework. Based on what you sent, it looks like it's not.